# Problems with Lazy Loading with Proxies EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I built two classes below as shown in this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy, to apply lazy loading with proxies to the database contexts in my project, but the following error message is thrown.

> Entity type 'Version' is sealed. 'UseChangeTrackingProxies' requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual properties, and have a public or protected constructor. 'UseLazyLoadingProxies' requires only the navigation properties be virtual.

```
public class Document
{
      public long Id {get; set;}
      .....
      public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
      public Document() {}
}

public class Version 
{
       public long Original_Document_Id { get; set; }
      .....
       [ForeignKey(nameof(Original_Document_Id))]
       public virtual Document Original_Document { get; set; }

       public Version(){}
}
```

Could anyone guide me the possible solution for this error? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Looks like you mapped the .Net Version class.